# Redirecting Crawler to internal service

Tags: facebook, nginx, service, web-crawler

I want to setup nginx to have certain crawlers get data from an internal service running on port 9998.

So for instance, when a browser requests www.mywebsite.com/resource/1 it will look at the root folder but when the same resource is requested by a crawler (for instance the FB crawler) it should get the page returned by the service at 127.0.0.1:9998/resource/1.

This is the config I came up with but doesn't work as intended. The user agent is correctly identified, but the data is not obtained from the service.

```
    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~ Facebot) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9998;
        }

        root /etc/www/website;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        ... other stuff...
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `break` after the `proxy_pass`.

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Facebot) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9998;
        break;
    }

    root /etc/www/website;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    ... other stuff...
}
```